# Laplace approximation of an integral for which $w(x^\star)$ vanishes

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics, laplace-method

Consider the following real integral
$$
\int_{a}^b dx~ w(x)\exp[-N f(x)]
$$
and assume that $f(x)$ is twice-differentiable in $(a,b)$, and there exists a unique minimum point $x^\star\in (a,b)$ for $f$ - i.e. $f'(x^\star)=0$ and $f''(x^\star)>0$.

The standard Laplace approximation states that the integral can be approximated as
$$
\approx w(x^\star)\exp[-N f(x^\star)]\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{Nf''(x^\star)}} .
$$

But what if $w(x^\star)=0$? How should the "classical" formula above be modified?

For example, we know by exact evaluation that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^3 dx~ x \exp[-N x^2]=-\frac{e^{-9N}}{2N} .
$$
But how can I retrieve the expression on the r.h.s. (which is *already* the correct asymptotic expansion) using the Laplace approximation? The argmin of the function $x^2$ in the exponent is at $x=0$, but this value will kill the function $w(x)=x$....

Comment: The integral over $[-3, 3]$ is zero, so we can apply Laplace's method to the integral from $-\infty$ to $-3$:
$$\int_{-\infty}^3 x e^{-N x^2} dx \sim
-3 \int_{-\infty}^{-3} e^{N (-9 + 6 (x + 3))} dx.$$
If we want to approximate $\int_0^a x^p e^{-N x^2} dx$, then we have to evaluate $\int_0^\infty x^p e^{-N x^2} dx$, which gives a gamma function.